# Share a folder with external use using PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp

I am trying to share a folder with an external user, I get the URL of the folder on console.log. But how can I send it directly to the user?

> This code shares a file with an external user, but it can't send an email in order to inform him. Any suggestion?

```
sp
 .web
 .getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/contoso/SharedFiles/test")
 .shareWith("mymail@gmail.com", SharingRole.View, true, true, { body: 'test' })
 .then((result: SharingResult) => {
    console.log(result);
 })
```

Comment: thank you for editing Mohamed.

Answer (score 0):

**This code works fine**, in addition you can add in email property a subject. My bad it sent into the junk box.